# Python qrcode module generating qrcode with data not in source code

Tags: python, django

I'm creating an app for tracking stock using qr codes, I'm writing my app using Django and am using the qrcode module for generating qrcodes for items. In a previous version of my app the data I passed to the qrcode.make() function was different for the url it was representing. For some reason when generating the first wetsuit item, the qr code generated uses the old data for the url even though it's not present in my code. All other items work fine and any wetsuit instance after the first one generates a correct qr code with the correct data.

My app is on my github [here](https://github.com/rsbennett22/Brumsurf-Stock-App) a folder named qrcodes in the static folder for the app to work correctly

And the relevant code snippets:

```
def generateQRCode(stockType, number, fileName):
    print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Generating a new "+stockType+" QR code..."+bcolors.ENDC)
    #Generate qrcode from data
    qrData = 'http://192.168.0.72:8000/detail/'+stockType+'&'+str(number)
    print(bcolors.FAIL+qrData+bcolors.ENDC)
    qr = qrcode.make(qrData)
    print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Saving generated QR code..."+bcolors.ENDC)
    path = 'static/qrcodes/'+fileName
    qr.save(path)
    if(exists(path)):
        return print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully generated and saved QR code!"+bcolors.ENDC)
    else:
        return print(bcolors.FAIL+"QR code failed to save!"+bcolors.ENDC)
```

For some reason wetsuit instance 1's qrData is being generated as if the code below was written instead of what is in the snippet above:

```
'ip address'+stockType+'/'+brand+'&'+gender+'&'+size+'&'+number
```

EDIT:
Heres my views.py file

```
def addNewItem(request):
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        stockType=''
        brand=''
        gender=''
        size=''
        number=''
        #Check stockType
        if(request.POST.get('stockType')=='Wetsuit'):
            print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Setting wetsuit specific details..."+bcolors.ENDC)
            stockType = 'wetsuit'
            gender = request.POST.get('gender')
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully set details: stockType: "+stockType+" and gender: "+gender+"!"+bcolors.ENDC)
        elif(request.POST.get('stockType')=='Surfboard'):
            print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Setting stocktype to surfboard..."+bcolors.ENDC)
            stockType = 'surfboard'
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully set stocktype to surfboard!"+bcolors.ENDC)
        elif(request.POST.get('stockType')=='Surfskate'):
            print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Setting stocktype to surfskate..."+bcolors.ENDC)
            stockType = 'surfskate'
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully set stocktype to surfskate!"+bcolors.ENDC)
        elif(request.POST.get('stockType')=='Boot'):
            print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Setting stocktype to boot..."+bcolors.ENDC)
            stockType = 'boot'
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully set stocktype to boot!"+bcolors.ENDC)
        elif(request.POST.get('stockType')=='Glove'):
            print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Setting stocktype to glove..."+bcolors.ENDC)
            stockType = 'glove'
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully set stocktype to glove!"+bcolors.ENDC)
        else:
            print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Setting stocktype to hood..."+bcolors.ENDC)
            stockType = 'hood'
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully set stocktype to hood!"+bcolors.ENDC)

        print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Attempting to add new "+stockType+" to db..."+bcolors.ENDC)
        brand = request.POST.get('brand')
        size = request.POST.get('size')
        if(size==None):
            size=''
        print(bcolors.FAIL+str(request.POST)+bcolors.ENDC)
        number = checkForMatchingNum(stockType, request.POST.get('num'))
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Retrieved item info: "+stockType, brand, gender, str(size), str(number)+bcolors.ENDC)
        
        if(stockType=='boot' or stockType=='glove' or stockType=='hood'):
            if(stockType=='boot'):
                #Check for matching item
                try:
                    matchingBoot = Boot.objects.get(brand=brand, size=size)
                    #If match item, load detail page
                    return accessoryDetail(request, matchingBoot.pk)
                except:
                    #No matching item
                    #Set amount and save
                    amount = request.POST.get('amount')
                    #Create new boot instance
                    newBoot = Boot()
                    newBoot.stockType=stockType
                    newBoot.brand=brand
                    newBoot.size=size
                    newBoot.bootAmount=amount
                    newBoot.url=''
                    #Save boot
                    newBoot.save()
                    #Get newboot pk
                    bootMade = Boot.objects.get(brand=brand, size=size)
                    pk = bootMade.pk
                    bootMade.url = 'http://192.168.0.75:8000/detail/'+str(pk)
                    bootMade.save()
                    #Load accessory details page
                    return accessoryDetail(request, pk)
            elif(stockType=='glove'):
                #Check for matching item
                try:
                    matchingGlove = Glove.objects.get(brand=brand, size=size)
                    #If match item, load detail page
                    return accessoryDetail(request, matchingGlove.pk)
                except:
                    #No matching item
                    #Set amount and save
                    amount = request.POST.get('amount')
                    #Create new boot instance
                    newGlove = Glove()
                    newGlove.stockType=stockType
                    newGlove.brand=brand
                    newGlove.size=size
                    newGlove.gloveAmount=amount
                    newGlove.url=''
                    #Save boot
                    newGlove.save()
                    #Get newboot pk
                    gloveMade = Glove.objects.get(brand=brand, size=size)
                    pk = gloveMade.pk
                    gloveMade.url = 'http://192.168.0.75:8000/detail/'+str(pk)
                    gloveMade.save()
                    #Load accessory details page
                    return accessoryDetail(request, pk)
            else:
                #Check for matching item
                try:
                    matchingHood = Hood.objects.get(brand=brand, size=size)
                    #If match item, load detail page
                    return accessoryDetail(request, matchingHood.pk)
                except:
                    #No matching item
                    #Set amount and save
                    amount = request.POST.get('amount')
                    #Create new boot instance
                    newHood = Hood()
                    newHood.stockType=stockType
                    newHood.brand=brand
                    newHood.size=size
                    newHood.hoodAmount=amount
                    newHood.url=''
                    #Save boot
                    newHood.save()
                    #Get newboot pk
                    hoodMade = Hood.objects.get(brand=brand, size=size)
                    pk = hoodMade.pk
                    hoodMade.url = 'http://192.168.0.75:8000/detail/'+str(pk)
                    hoodMade.save()
                    #Load accessory details page
                    return accessoryDetail(request, pk)
                
        else:
            #Create a filename for the qr code using data from request
            fileName=stockType+brand+gender+str(size)+str(number)+'.png'
            #Check if qr code matchng filename exists
            if(checkForQR(fileName)):
                #Load surfboard info page
                return itemDetail(request, stockType, number)
            else:
                #Generate QR code for item
                generateQRCode(stockType, number, fileName)
                #Create a new item object and add it to db
                if(stockType=='wetsuit'):
                    print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Creating a new "+stockType+" instance!"+bcolors.ENDC)
                    newWetsuit = Wetsuit()
                    newWetsuit.stockType=stockType
                    newWetsuit.brand=brand
                    newWetsuit.gender=gender
                    newWetsuit.size=size
                    newWetsuit.wetsuitNumber=number
                    newWetsuit.qrCode=fileName
                    newWetsuit.url='http://192.168.0.75:8000/detail/'+stockType+'&'+str(number)
                    print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"New wetsuit info: "+str(newWetsuit)+bcolors.ENDC)
                    newWetsuit.save()
                    print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully created a new "+stockType+" instance!"+bcolors.ENDC)
                    return itemDetail(request, stockType, number)
                elif(stockType=='surfboard'):
                    print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Creating a new "+stockType+" instance!"+bcolors.ENDC)
                    newBoard = Surfboard()
                    newBoard.stockType=stockType
                    newBoard.brand=brand
                    newBoard.size=size
                    newBoard.surfboardNumber=number
                    newBoard.qrCode=fileName
                    newBoard.url='http://192.168.0.75:8000/detail/'+stockType+'&'+str(number)
                    newBoard.save()
                    print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully created a new "+stockType+" instance!"+bcolors.ENDC)
                    return itemDetail(request, stockType, number)
                elif(stockType=='surfskate'):
                    print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Creating a new "+stockType+" instance!"+bcolors.ENDC)
                    newBoard = Surfskate()
                    newBoard.stockType=stockType
                    newBoard.brand=brand
                    newBoard.size=size
                    newBoard.surfskateNumber=number
                    newBoard.qrCode=fileName
                    newBoard.url='http://192.168.0.75:8000/detail/'+stockType+'&'+str(number)
                    newBoard.save()
                    print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully created a new "+stockType+" instance!"+bcolors.ENDC)
                    return itemDetail(request, stockType, number)

def generateQRCode(stockType, number, fileName):
    print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Generating a new "+stockType+" QR code..."+bcolors.ENDC)
    #Generate qrcode from data
    qrData = 'http://192.168.0.75:8000/detail/'+stockType+'&'+str(number)
    print(bcolors.FAIL+qrData+bcolors.ENDC)
    qr = qrcode.make(qrData)
    print(bcolors.OKGREEN+"Saving generated QR code..."+bcolors.ENDC)
    path = 'static/qrcodes/'+fileName
    qr.save(path)
    if(exists(path)):
        return print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"Successfully generated and saved QR code!"+bcolors.ENDC)
    else:
        return print(bcolors.FAIL+"QR code failed to save!"+bcolors.ENDC)

def checkForMatchingNum(stockType, number):
    #Check if item with same item num exists
    try:
        #If item found with Id, get next available
        if(stockType=='wetsuit'):
            numItem = Wetsuit.objects.get(wetsuitNumber=number)
            number = getNextNum(1, 'wetsuit')
            return number
        elif(stockType=='surfboard'):
            numItem = Surfboard.objects.get(surfboardNumber=number)
            number = getNextNum(1, 'surfboard')
            return number
        elif(stockType=='surfskate'):
            numItem = Surfskate.objects.get(surfskateNumber=number)
            number = getNextNum(1, 'surfskate')
            return number
    except:
        #If not found, continue
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE+stockType+" number is ok!"+bcolors.ENDC)
        return number

def getNextNum(number, stockType):
    if(stockType=='wetsuit'):
        try:
            #If no exception, recursive call number+1
            availableNum = Wetsuit.objects.get(wetsuitNumber=number)
            num = number + 1
            return getNextNum(num, 'wetsuit')
        except:
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"New number: "+str(number)+bcolors.ENDC)
            return number
    elif(stockType=='surfboard'):
        try:
            #If no exception, recursive call number+1
            availableNum = Surfboard.objects.get(surfboardNumber=number)
            num = number + 1
            return getNextNum(num, 'surfboard')
        except:
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"New number: "+str(number)+bcolors.ENDC)
            return number
    elif(stockType=='surfskate'):
        try:
            #If no exception, recursive call number+1
            availableNum = Surfskate.objects.get(surfskateNumber=number)
            num = number + 1
            return getNextNum(num, 'surfskate')
        except:
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"New number: "+str(number)+bcolors.ENDC)
            return number

def checkForQR(fileName):
    path = 'static/qrcodes/'+fileName
    print(path)
    if(exists(path)):
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE+"QR code already exists!"+bcolors.ENDC)
        return True
    else:
        print(bcolors.WARNING+"QR code does not exist!"+bcolors.ENDC)
        return False
```

Comment: The problem is probably in the code that calls `generateQRCode` which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Apologies, added my views.py file now

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code; not sure it helped.  You should try to pare it down to a [mre].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ah my bad, trimmed to relevant functions now